# Is static reference faster than declaration/reference?

Tags: java, performance, static, styles, declaration

I want to run a method at program shutdown which requires a temp variable to an object reference to be stored. I just so happen to have a class variable of the same type that I've been using this whole time to store the current value, and it's no longer needed.

I know it's probably not best practice, but if I want to save the extra step and write an object reference as a placeholder while my program does some housekeeping, would it be faster to write it to this variable which already exists than to declare a fresh temp from scratch? The static variable is in another class, if that makes a difference.

"So fast it doesn't matter," and either way an object gets written. I'm just trying to understand how these things work in memory. The glaring issue with a new variable seems to me that it's a declaration which has to allocate some space on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reusing some unrelated class variable is the worst choice. It makes your code unreadable and unmaintainable.
2. Allocating an additional reference variable on the stack also doesn't take time - it doesn't matter whether your method has 5 or 50 local variables. Allocating local variables means just adding/subtracting some (constant) value from the stack pointer.
3. Forget about allocating space on the disk - the state of your running program is normally not written to the disk at all.